# Cannot connect to a SharePoint site from InfoPath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Product installed:
SharePoint Trial

Here are the steps that I made:

a. Create a list.

[image]

b. Connect to a site.

[image]

c. Error occurs.

[image]

What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Top-level** site is mandatory.